# последовательность Коллатца

Tags: python

Новичек в Python, решаю задачи Эйлера, в данный момент на этой задаче https://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/14.html
Задачу всегда начинаю решать с меньшего, поэтому тестирую ядро.
Вопрос...Почему когда *number < 2* у меня не исполняется код?

```
number = 3
boolFlag = True
while boolFlag:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number / 2
    if numberi % 2 != 0:
        number = number * 3 + 1  
    if number < 2:
        boolFlag = False
    #print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код исполняется. Просто представьте, что вы - компьютер и проработайте каждую строку вслух (представим, что мы сделали `number = 1`):

1. boolFlag == True ? - да, идем в тело цикла
2. 1 (`number`) % 2 == 0 ? - нет, идем дальше
3. 1 % 2 !=0 ? - да, а значит number = 4 (number*3 + 1 = 1*3+1)
4. 4 < 2 ? - нет, идем дальше.
5. boolFlag == True ? - да, идем в тело цикла.
6. 4 % 2 == 0 ? - да, number = 2 (number / 2 = 4/2)
7. 2 % 2 != 0 ? - нет, идем дальше
8. 2 < 2 ? - нет, идем дальше
9. ...

---

Вам нужно использовать `elif`, чтобы после выполнения первого условия вы не проверяли втрое и третье, а после выполнения второго - третье.
То есть:

```
number = 3
boolFlag = True
while boolFlag:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number / 2
    elif numberi % 2 != 0:
        number = number * 3 + 1  
    elif number < 2:
        boolFlag = False
    #print(i)
```

Еще нужно сначала проверить `number < 2`, а потом уже другое:

```
number = 3
boolFlag = True
while boolFlag:
    if number < 2:
        boolFlag = False
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        number = number / 2
    elif numberi % 2 != 0:
        number = number * 3 + 1  
    #print(i)
```